# Div expanding to fit content even when width and height explicitly set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

If I set a `div`'s dimensions to be 100 by 100 pixels using `$.attr()`, and set a canvas within it to be 150 by 150 pixels, again using `$.attr()` to avoid stretching the canvas, the div automagically expands to fit its contents. Why is this, and how can I make sure the `div` cuts off the canvas? I have `overflow: hidden` on the `div` and want to use it to display only a portion of the canvas. However, all of the canvas is displaying.

Here's a [fiddle of my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/TLC9r/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the CSS size of the container and the element size of the canvas:

```
$("#container").css("width", 100);
$("#container").css("height", 100);

$("canvas").attr("width", 150);
$("canvas").attr("height", 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

`width` and `height` are not valid style attributes, and certinaly not just numerical ones.

Use `width()` and `height()` or `css()` to set inline style properties. Can pass numeric value representing pixels to all 3

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TLC9r/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: The canvas gets stretched if you apply CSS attributes to it or any of its parents, though. I need a way to do it through HTML attributes, not CSS. It's not clearly visible in the demo, because all that's rendered on the canvas is a black box, but if I were to render an image, it would become more clear.

Comment: ok..I threw that together quick, for DIV you have to use `style`... I don't do a lot with canvas. Can keep aspect ratio with a little bit of calculating